# Example of a colloquium exam

Tags: c, task

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyppH.jpg) 
This is my 1st post so have that in mind while reading my question.
I have an exam of a colloquium but my code does not provide me the correct result.
So if anyone could help me that would be great. :)
These are the informations that are provided in the exam:
A function *y=f(x)=ax^2+bx+c*
We have to find the surface that is below the chart but keep in mind that dx(Delta X)=B-A and the height goes like this: A,A+dx,A+2dx, .... , B-dx.
As dx value gets lower the surface will be more accurate.
You have to write the program so that the surface with precision 0.001
This is my code so could someone who is good in C check it please.
Thank you.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    double A,B,dx,p,D,q,x,y,nv,nv1,nv2,sv;
    do{
        printf("Insert a & b: "),scanf("%lf %lf",&A,&B);
    } while(A<1 || B<1);
    nv=dx=B-A;
    do{
        printf("enter odds: "),scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
        p=(-b)/2;
        D=sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c);
        q= -D/4*a;
    } while( a<0 || p<0 || q<0);
    do{
        sv=nv;
        dx/=2;
        nv=0;
        for(x=A;x<p;x+=dx)
        for(dx=B-A;dx<q;dx/=2)
            nv1+=x*dx;
        for(y=p;y<=B;y+=dx)
        for(dx=q;dx<B;dx/=2)
            nv2+=y*dx;
        nv=nv1+nv2;
    }while(fabs(nv-sv)>0.001);
    printf("The surface is %lf",nv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know if this code is correct or not". That's what testing is for. So have you tested your code and if so, did you find any problems?

Comment: I've tested my code but it does not provide the correct answer.
I've receive the same value of nv = 43510000...000, so I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint what to fix it.

Comment: Testing, analyzing the results and debugging is the usual way of fixing apps.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the approximation of a definite integral of a quadratic function. There are several issues with your code:

- What is the restriction of *A ≥ 1* and *B ≥ 1* for? A parabola is defined over the whole abscissa. If anything, you should enforce that the input is numeric and that two values were given.
- You don't need to find the vertex of the parabola. Your task is to create small rectangles based on the left *x* value of each interval as the image shows. Therefore, you don't need *p* and *q*. And you shouldn't enforce that the vertex is in the first quadrant on the input without indication.
- Why are the coefficients of the parabola integers? Make them `double`s to be consistent.
- Because you don't need to know the vertex, you don't need to split your loop in two. In your code, you don't even check that *p* is between *A* and *B*, which is a requirement of cour code.
- What is the inner loop for? You are supposed to just calculate the area of the current rectangle here. What's worse: you re-use the variable `dx` as iteration variable, which means you lose it as an indicator of how large your current interval is.
- The repeated incrementing of `dx` may lead to an accumulated floating-point error when the number of intervals is large. A common technique to avoid this is to use an integer variable for loop control and the determine the actual floating-point variable by multiplication.
- The absolute value as a convergence criterion may lead to problems with small and big numbers. The iteration ends too early for small values and it may never reach the criterion for big numbers, where a difference of 0.001 cannot be resolved.

Here's a version of your code that puts all that into practice:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    double A, B;

    printf("Lower and upper limit A, B: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &A, &B);

    printf("enter coefficients a, b, c: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);

    double nv = 0;
    double sv;
    int n = 1;

    do {
        int i;
        double dx;

        sv = nv;

        n *= 2;
        dx = (B - A) / n;
        nv = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double x = A + i * (B - A) / n;
            double y = a*x*x + b*x + c;

            nv += dx * y;
        }
    } while(fabs(nv - sv) > 0.0005 * fabs(nv + sv));

    printf("Surface: %lf\n", nv);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is well-behaved for empty intervals (where *A* = *B*) or reversed intervals (where *A* > *B*). The inpt is still quick and dirty. It should really heck that the entered values are valid numbers. There's no need to restrict the input arbitrarily, though.

Comment: Thank you so much .
I needed to put A ≥ 1 and B ≥ 1  because it says so in the exam (the interval (A,B) uses just positive numbers.
 I've used the absolute value because we have used that type do define a precission (like in this example precission=0.001).
Anyways,thank you very much once again.